# What prevents an as from announcing false ip addresses?

Tags: bgp, address

In BGP an AS could announce paths for arbitrary IP addresses, resulting in false routings. Is there a mechanism that prevents such actions?

Comment: Not only is this possible, there are well-known cases in the relatively recent past.

Comment: There's no such mechanism, moreover, there were multiple attacks based on exactly this behavior.